# Default value for first parameter in route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have route which shows paintings by genre, tag, style, etc for multilanguage website.

It looks not bad, something like

```
en/Genre/allegorical-painting
```

But, what client wants is to exclude **en** for english language and get just

```
Genre/allegorical-painting
```

I have "en" as default, but it is rendered all the time... when i remove it manually i have 404 error. Here is my rule definition:

```
var searchActionsConstraint = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Style|Tag|Painting-School|Art-Movement|Artist-by-Genre|Gallery|Search|Genre|Technique|Material" }, {"lang", "en|es|fr"} };
DomainRoute wikiSearchRoute = new Route("{lang}/{action}/{SearchTerm}/{CurrentPage}/{SearchCategory}/{searchTextMode}",
new RouteValueDictionary(new
{
 lang = "en",
 controller = "WikiSearch",
 action = "",
 SearchTerm = "Any",
 CurrentPage = "1",
 SearchCategory = "Painting",
 searchTextMode = "SearchTags"
}), searchActionsConstraint, new DomainRouteHandler());

RouteTable.Routes.Add("WikiSearchRoute", wikiSearchRoute);
```

in general, how can I hide default route parameter in MVC when it is first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a second route without the lang, and specify the default for it

```
DomainRoute wikiSearchRouteEn = new Route("{action}/{SearchTerm}/{CurrentPage}/{SearchCategory}/{searchTextMode}",
new RouteValueDictionary(new
{
 lang = "en",
 controller = "WikiSearch",
 action = "",
 SearchTerm = "Any",
 CurrentPage = "1",
 SearchCategory = "Painting",
 searchTextMode = "SearchTags"
}), searchActionsConstraint, new DomainRouteHandler());

RouteTable.Routes.Add("WikiSearchRouteEn", wikiSearchRouteEn);
```